# Why does notification Intent from a separate process launch a new instance of my activity, disregarding android:launchMode?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, android-service, android-notifications

My application consists of an activity and a service with `android:process=":service"`. In `onStart()`, the activity binds to a messenger class of the service. In `onStop()`, it unbinds. There is also a switch button which, when toggled on calls `startService()` and sends a service on message, which tells the service to `startForeground()`, and when toggled off, it calls `stopService()` and sends a message which tells the service to `stopForeground()`. All of this seems to work just fine.

When the switch button is toggled on, the foreground notification is displayed. I can back out of the activity, change the screen orientation, lock/unlock the phone, and when I relaunch the activity from its icon, the state of the toggle switch is still on. When I toggle it off, the service notification goes away as designed.

The foreground notification is programmed to launch the activity when it is touched. However, the switch button is reset back to the off stated. I believe a new instance is starting because I see that `onStart()` is called before `onStop()`. I assume this is indicating that this is the `onStart()` of the new instance and the `onStop()` of the old instance with the button state I wanted to save. I have tried every value of `android:launchMode` and tried many different flag choices for the notification's pendingintent. Nothing changes this behavior.

However, if I run the service in the same process as the activity, the state of the buttons is retained. Why? I cannot find anything in the literature to explain this.

My first theory was that the notification tried to launch the activity in the service's process, but I have defined a specific, different, process for the activity, and the behavior persists.

Comment: Hello there! This question was posted quite a while ago but if you've been able to find any solution to the issue, would you mind sharing here? I'm having the same kind of problem with a music player app.

Comment: In my case, the Activity is not recreated but the system forces Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK because startActivity() was called from a non-Activity context.

Comment: Never got it working :(

Comment: I just found out that my problem does not exist. Turns out there's something wrong with my primary test device. Probably the custom ROM that I'm using.

Comment: I also have a service running in another process but the the Activity is never recreated when opened with the notification.

Comment: By the way, changing orientation causes an Activity to be recreated. You might wanna look into saving and restoring instance state. I have overridden the default behaviour of the back button to minimize the app instead of destroying the main activity. This way, reopening the app is faster and smoother.